# Xcode 10 playground is not showing the output

Tags: swift-playground, xcode10

I am using Xcode 10 on macOS Mojave 10.14.4. When I open the playground I am unable to get the output window to output anything, even using the print command it stays blank. Is there any other program for mac that shows output as you code in swift? Or has anyone encountered and was able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Swift playgrounds can be flaky. To see any output you first have to run the playground. Look at the screenshot of an empty Mac playground where I added a line to print the contents of the `str` variable:

[image]

If you move the mouse over the left side of the editor, a Run button will appear, which you can see at Line 3 in the screenshot. Clicking that button will run that line of code. Clicking the Run playground button will run the whole playground. The results will appear in the right side of the window. Some output will also appear in the debug area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with a similar problem and tried different solutions - nothing worked for me. While I was able to run playground via command-line, I was not able to run it in XCode (for me it looked like nothing was printed in console). Finally discovered that **Cylance** antivirus was silently terminating my playground scripts. Uninstalling Cylance solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've submitted a review of interrupt's answer which is pending. I'm posting this second answer so others can see it quicker.

I had the same issue as interrupt did. However, you don't have to uninstall Cylance.

Simply going to Cylance Dashboard and whitelist your application to allow Xcode to execute your code to generate output.

** EDIT **

After some investigation, performing the steps I've previously mentioned  (now removed), will only be a temporary fix. When a new instance of Xcode launches and the project is opened once again, Cylance will flag it as Potential Unwanted Program (PUP).

I've emailed Cylance support team as I am a current subscriber and I was given the following answer

> Hello XXXXXXX,
>
> I have ran two SHA's in your quarantine against the system and both of
>   them have appeared as "PUP ScriptingTool". If you can sign these files
>   with a certificate, then they might not get detected and quarantined.
>
> -Michael

Cylance advertises themselves as "Next Gen EndPoint Detection and Recovery" product using AI. And yet, it flags my "hello world" program. The "fix" was to generate a certificate for the app, which tells me that it flags all unsigned apps as PUP. That is not smart! I now stand by interupt's answer.

Delete CylanceProtect and stay away from this app.